# How to capture redirect response header

Tags: redirect, jmeter

I am trying to record a simple login and logout flow for a .Net application. After I submit the login credentials the welcome page's URL has a large alpha numeric number. This number is required to continue to the next steps.

On Fiddler I have noticed that the login credential submission request results in a 302 response and this response contain an `a=129characterstring` that i need in my subsequent requests.

On JMeter I have added a recording controller and on the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder I have Follow Redirects and Use KeepAlive checked (See below screenshot)
[image: HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder settings]

I have also recorded with Follow Redirects unchecked and different options for Grouping and HTTP Sampler Settings.

But with none of them I am able to record/capture the 302 response that i see on fiddler. Instead the login credential submission request always returns a 200 response, even if the login fails.

It is not as if that JMeter is not recording redirect requests, further down the scenario flow I have another redirect request which is captured.

I can't be the only one who is/has faced this problem. Does anyone have any suggestions on what I should be doing differently to get the 302 response?

Comment: Sorry I was just able to see your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this:

- Record with default options, the redirect Http Request triggered by 302 will be disabled by default.

Then you will need after this to uncheck "Follow Redirect" in the first one, and add a Regular Expression Post Processor to extract the data you want.

Then enable the commented second request and inject the extracted variable.

Comment: What do you mean by default options? Do you mean the default options of the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder? I don't think 302 are disabled because when I record another redirect gets captured just not the one I want. I have tried by unchecking the Follow Redirect on the cred submit request and I keep getting a 200 response.

Comment: Yes I mean the default options of the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder, Yes they are disabled, meaning when you record and a 302 happens, then JMeter will create 1 sampler for the initial Request and 1 sampler for the request triggered by 302 but this one will be disabled. I you get a 200 response then you are probably missing a correlation during replay which leads to the failure of your request that should trigger a 302, so it does not trigger it

Comment: I agree with you on the 200 response. I thought I correlated everything but going through it again to find whatever I missed.

Comment: One of the components was not running and hence I was not getting the expected 302 response. I just activated it and got the response.